# How to select Listbox value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a ListBox in my webpage that is bound from database in this way:

```
    ListBox1.DataTextField = "Text";
    ListBox1.DataValueField = "MenuID";
    ListBox1.DataSource = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(DAL.DALBase.ConnectionString, "GetMenu");
    ListBox1.DataBind();
```

I want to get selected item value and used this code but have a error and does not worked.

```
ListBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Forgive me if I have problems on how to write because my English is not good.

Comment: When I use form ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value i get Object not refrence to an instance error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you be more specific on the error you are getting?

Using `ListBox1.SelectedValue` should work.

For example:

```
int mySelectedValue = int.Parse(ListBox1.SelectedValue);
```

or

```
string mySelectedValue = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
```

### Edit

Added code to ensure the original poster was keeping values in ListBox databound.

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
       BindListBox();
   }
}

private BindListBox()
{
   ListBox1.DataTextField = "Text";
   ListBox1.DataValueField = "MenuID";
   ListBox1.DataSource = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(DAL.DALBase.ConnectionString, "GetMenu");
   ListBox1.DataBind();
}

protected void SomeButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string mySelectedValue = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Also provide your .Net version as this is done a bit differently in earlier versions.

Comment: When I select a row of this ListBox and press button to submit that string returned to me ("" means null) but I selected a row. I need ListBox value that is ID to get menu from database by this ID.

Comment: @Johnny DropTables: I've used this in .NET 2.0 onwards.

Comment: @Farzad Salehi: Have you debugged to see if your SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(DAL.DALBase.ConnectionString, "GetMenu"); is returning any rows? I believe the issue could be the fact your ListBox is losing its data on postback. I will update my post.

Comment: Your answer is very well! That losing its data on postback. Thank you very much. ;)

Comment: @Farzad Salehi: Thank you. If my answer helped. Please mark the post as correct. :-)